# Play Framework 2.4.x. Redis module 2.4.0. could not serialize: java.io.NotSerializableException: play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi

Tags: scala, playframework, redis

I use Play Framework 2.4.x with Redis Module 2.4.0

```
"com.typesafe.play.modules" %% "play-modules-redis" % "2.4.0"
```

...

```
resolvers += "google-sedis-fix" at "http://pk11-scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk"
```

...

```
modules.disabled += "play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"
```

When I try to cache some entities (e.g Devices) I get error:

```
could not serialize key: .... and value: ......  ex:java.io.NotSerializableException: play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi
```

But it works for other entities (e.g Users)

Please help to cache

Thanks

Comment: What does 'Devices' look like? If it has a dependency to MessagesApi (which I suspect) and if you really need that there as instance ref (which I doubt) you could mark that as transient.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @rethab. That class contains a lot other classes one of whitch extended trait with Messages.Implicits.applicationMessages. I think that was a reason of the error. But I did lot other changes that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed implicit with Messages.Implicits.applicationMessages that halped